# declare an ArrayList with multiple types

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I want to declare an `ArrayList` with multiple types, to be more clear to do as the following :

```
public ArrayList<Integer, String, Boolean> a = new ArrayList<Integer, String, Boolean>();
```

I know that example will not work because `ArrayList` can be parameterized with only one type argument.

The `HashMap` can allow me to use two arguments, but that's not enough in my case.

I know that I can declare a class with multiple attributes and use it as a parameter in my `ArrayList`, but I don't want this method.

Isn't there any method to declare a `List` with multiple types, or to use some `internal class` to do that?

Comment: _"I know that I can declare a class with multiple attributes and use it as a parameter in my ArrayList, but I don't want this method."_ Why?

Comment: how would you know which type is the object you get from the array, then?

Comment: I think he wants to restrict the array to these 3 types (but only one at a time). Since they're final, he'll have to create 3 wrapper classes that implement some common interface and then create an arraylist of this interface type

Comment: @ZouZou because then ArrayList I want to declare is static and I'll use it only one time, so there is no need to declare a whole class for that

Comment: @Leo could you be more clear, please.

Comment: @MAJDOUAimad just wondering if you want an arraylist of a type that contains at the same time Boolean,String and Integer, or if what you want is an ArrayList that accepts only 1 type, but this type must be a Boolena OR a String OR an Integer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Leo I want an arraylist of a type that contains at the same time Boolean,String and Integer

Answer (score 3):

You can create it like this

```
public class Tuple<A, B, C> {
    public A First;
    public B Second;
    public C Third;    
}
```

and you declare  it like this

```
List< Tuple <Integer, String, Bool> listOfTuple;
```

or check this out javatuples  http://www.javatuples.org for Tuples from 1-10 Params

Answer (score 1):

The [Table](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Table.html) structure in Guava seems to meet all of your needs nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use polymorphism, create an interface lets say ListElement. All the objects you want to add to this list must implement this interface. Then just use an ArrayList of ListElement

The other possibility (since you are using classes like Integer) you can use a ArrayList of Object, since all objects extend the class Object.